# Pass Dynamic table from one html page to another html page

Tags: javascript, html

I have created html table by adding rows dynamically in one html page and i need to access the entire table from other page for deleting the selected row form table,using javascript,can anyone help me in solving this?

Comment: Please put what you have tried as this is your first post please read how to ask also....

Comment: You will need to store the table somewhere. Have a look at the localStorage API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

Comment: tbl = $('#dataTable').html();
localStorage.setItem('edittable', JSON.stringify(tbl));
var tablevalue=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('edittable'));

I have saved the table in a variable tbl and again i saved in local storage,now i am getting table values in other html page,now i need to delete rows from this table using row index.

Comment: can you elaborate your requirement. Please provide some screen shots or code samples for better understanding

Comment: In first.html I have table with dynamic rows,i need to delete table rows from second.html page,to do that i have saved the table in local storage,now i am getting table in second.html,but i need to know how to delete rows form it.

Answer (score 0):

In **first.html**
Suppose your table is inside a div called 'mydiv'

```
<div id='mydiv'>
<table> .... </table>

</div>
```

Now before going to 'second.html' perform this in javascript in 'first.html'

```
   var htmlcontent = document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML;
```

set htmlcontent to a cookie  called 'mycookie'

in **second.html**

```
   get htmlcontent from cookie
   set it as innerHTML of a div 'destinationdiv' in second.html
```

Comment: But keep in mind that cookies can only store 4k of data per domain.